# Delay in loading css for angular-routed pages

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-routing

I am using angular routing in my dashboard, css for each routed page is loaded dynamically. so whenever i switch the tab, there is one second delay in loading the css, until then the page will be displayed without any styling. have a look at the code

```
angular.module('app')
    .config(function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('usercreate', {
                url: '/usercreate',
                parent: 'report',
                views: {
                    'nested@report': {
                        templateUrl: 'scripts/report/usercreate/usercreate.html',
                        controller: 'usercreateController'
                    }
                },
                data: {
                      css: 
                        'scripts/report/usercreate/usercreate.css'
                },
                resolve: {

                }
            });
    });
```

So,i want the routed page to be displayed only after the css is loaded..
any suggestions?

Comment: One way around would be to minify your CSS, this way it will load much faster.

Comment: actually the problem is only when the page is loaded for the first time.so,i don't think minifying all css files(around 30 in mycase) would be an ideal solution..

Comment: when you load page in first time , browser will download all file  and handle for you when you routing . This is reason why it problem occur when first time you loaded